# How to log out from Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, logout

I searched through the internet to find the way to logout from the site. One thing I found is delete the cookies from the browser.

Is there any other way to logout from the site?

Answer (score 4):

On the top left, there stands StackExchange. Click there, then a dropdown menu opens. There is on the right a button logout.

Answer (score 3):

Off-topic, but click on the `StackExchange` in the top left hand corner, and find the `log out` link next to `chat` and `blog`

Answer (score 3):

Click the Stack Exchange drop down. there is a option to log out in that.

Answer (score 2):

Click on **Stack Exchange** at Top Left corner . A window will open , you can see **Log out** option there at top right of window.